# How to save and load the keras history object, and add annotation on it in r?

Tags: r, keras

After the training and fitting with keras, we will get the history as ""keras_training_history" object, when we plot it with `plot(history)`, we get a ggplot object.

I would like to ask for advice.

1. how can I save and load the "keras_training_object" as i can do to the model with `save_model_hdf5` or `load_model_hdf5`?
2. besides, we can do some annotation on it with

`p <- plot(history)`

`p <- p + annotate(geom = "text", x = 10, y = 0.5, label = "Annotation Here", col = "red")`

my question is how to add specific text at specific position, instead of repeating it?

Since I don't know how to save it, or load it back, so sorry that I can't attach the file.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Without a reproducible example, there isn't much we can do to help troubleshoot: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html
You can look into `readRDS()` and `saveRDS()` for the objects

Comment: Many thanks, will modify for better description.